# Creating PHP application windows installer

Tags: php, installation

I have php project web application (php, html,js,css, wampserver, mssql database), im looking to make windows installer wizard so that when user wants to install this project in their PC, they just run installer wizard and install it.

Regards,
Raj

Comment: Why not have a self contained zip that gets extracted, an executable is run and then they go to a web interface for install?  A GUI will need something like PHP-GTK and is cumbersome.  Use the right tool for the job, choose another language.

Comment: You should use smth like that http://www.advancedinstaller.com/ and use the website package there. During installation your package is uppacking.